# Glitches on connection to the Alexa SEO service

Tags: seo, google-analytics, alexa

There were some glitches in the websites I am working on. The site was behaving weirdly and it was taking more time to load **only** in the USA.  But the same page in the websites was working fine in other countries. I tried loading that from the different internet on my side (i am on a different continent), but it was fine.

And when I tried to figure out the issues in the client's browser, I found that the browser is trying to connect to `certify.alexametrics.com`, and it is taking quite a few more time to load, sometimes it is taking 5-8sec to load.

Later, they told me that the sites are being tracked by Alexa SEO. But when I tried to find where the Alexa SEO is linked on the websites, I didn't find any code that references it.

But I found that the site has references to google analytics.

With all these things said, my questions are:

1. How was Alexa tracking the websites? and if in case a similar kind of situation occurs in the future how can we disable the tracking at that time?
2. And there are also some other services that are often being downloaded while browsing the sites if no ad-blocker is being installed. How to disable those sites?

I have attached the screenshot here.

Please help me with the query.

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting that screenshot that is showing the alexametrics line?

Comment: it was from the google chrome inspect!

Comment: Do you have the Alexa toolbar installed?

Comment: no, not at this moment. I don't have access to this application anymore now.

Comment: Did you have it installed when this screen shot was taken?

Comment: no it wasn't installed at that time.